# Split a string into an array of strings

Tags: c

It's been a while that I haven't written programs in C. I am used to write code in C#.

So, I want to split the user string input into an array of strings using a delimiter. 
I did this, but when I want to fetch the array I have a segmentation fault. 
As an example, I want just to print one element of the array.

I have checked on the net, but nothing worked.

Any hints ?

Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main ()
{

  char function[] = {};
  char * pch;
  int cpt = 0;
  int nb_terms = 0;

  printf("Entrez le nombre de termes :\n");
  scanf("%d", &nb_terms);

  char word[nb_terms];

  printf("Entrez votre fonction en n'utilisant que les 5 caractères suivants (a,b,c,d et +) :\n");
  scanf("%s", &function);

  pch = strtok (function,"+");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    word[cpt++] = pch;
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, "+");
  }

  printf ("%s\n",&word[1]);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your input and expected output?

Comment: `char function[] = {};`  what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: @wildplasser It's a GNU extension for a zero size array. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: You're getting the Segmentation fault because the array `function` is of a fixed size of none. Use a pointer to a char instead and allocate with malloc or establish a big enough size for the array.

Comment: warning are there not because the compiler writers hate you , but because they are trying to help

Comment: @pm100 But those warnings are off by default and complex to turn on because compiler writers hate you. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler warnings reveal your problems.

```
cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g   -c -o test.o test.c
test.c:7:21: warning: use of GNU empty initializer extension [-Wgnu-empty-initializer]
  char function[] = {};
                    ^
test.c:7:21: warning: zero size arrays are an extension [-Wzero-length-array]
test.c:18:15: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[0]'
      [-Wformat]
  scanf("%s", &function);
         ~~   ^~~~~~~~~
```

These are all related. `char function[] = {}` is a [GNU extension to declare a 0 size array](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html). Then you try to put stuff into it, but it's size 0. So there's going to be an overflow.

Instead, you need to allocate some space to `function` and be sure to limit `scanf` to only that size, no larger.

```
// {0} initializes all characters to 0.
// 1024 is a good size for a static input buffer.
char function[1024] = {0};

// one less because of the null byte
scanf("%1023s", &function);
```

---

The next warning...

```
test.c:23:17: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *';
      dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
    word[cpt++] = pch;
                ^ ~~~
                  *
```

is because you're trying to put the string (`char *`) `pch` where a character (`char`) goes. Even if you're only reading a single character from `strtok` (which you cannot guarantee) it always returns a string. You want an array of strings (`char **`). It also helps to have descriptive variable names.

```
char *word;                 // this was pch
char *words[nb_terms];      // this was word
```

After changing `pch` to `word`, and `word` to `words` in the rest of the code it all works.

```
  size_t word_idx = 0;
  for(
      char *word = strtok(function,"+");
      word != NULL;
      word = strtok(NULL, "+")
  ) {
      words[word_idx++] = word;
  }
```

I'll add [the usual caveats about `scanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).